Can I mark a function with noexcept if it has an argument passed by copy?
So I wanted to improve the noexcept of some operators and functions in my code
can I mark this function noexcept ?
std::string remove_suffix(/*passed by copy*/ std::string s) 
/*noexcept*/
// is noexcept allowed here?
{
    if(s[s.size()-1] == '0')
       s[0] = 'B';
    else
       s[0] = 'X';
    return s;
}

Can I mark this function noexcept and if it happens to throw an exception will it call std::terminate ?
I want to make sure of this so I can mark my addition operators for one my classes as noexcept to correct.

The only std::string constructor that is marked as noexpect is the rvalue (or "move") constructor. So marking your function as noexcept is likely not a good idea, exceptions can be thrown.

You can test this yourself, by making a class that always throws in copy ctor. IIRC parameters are constructed outside of the function, and are not covered by noexcept.

"Can I mark this function noexcept and if it happens to throw an exception will it call std::terminate ?" -- That is how noexcept is used, yes. And it is "allowed" on any function (even one that explicitly throws in its body). Perhaps you could be more specific about your concern? I think you meant to ask if an exception thrown from the constructor of the parameter (which occurs before the function call) would cause std::terminate to be called if the function is marked noexcept. (See also Exception guarantees and pass by value.)

I would not let it thru review anyway as it is undefined behavior when s is empty.

@ÖöTiib it is just an example function.this is not a real function in my code.

@JaMiT yes that is my concern

It would be far too complicated to let the called function do the copy, since most classes have many ways to create an object, and it's difficult to provide a million entry points depending on how parameters are provided. Instead, it's up to the caller to provide the objects as demanded by the function signature -- so yes, your function does not throw.

Parameters are constructed before calling into your function.  Your function's noexcept is applicable to your function after the parameters are all constructed. (If one of those parameter's constructors happens to throw, your function will never have been called, so your function's noexcept is not relevant.)

There's also a copy in the return, which could throw. I think this is in the body of the function, and so would violate the noexcept.

@ChristianStieber Hi, how about the returned value? (see James Kanze comment). Is it constructed by the function or the caller (btw, what would be the entry point on this topic in the standard? (or at least in cppreference))?

Unrelated, but take a look at std::string::front() and std::string::back().

@Oersted the return value is constructed by the function. In fact, it's constructed before things like local variables are destructed -- which allows the result value construction to be protected by a mutex, if necessary.

@ChristianStieber so i cant mark it noexcept then?

@user24551355 it would seem so. In general, I don't use noexcept for reasons such as these: you have to consider tiny little details, double check you don't miss anything, the compiler won't check it (like it does for trivial things like override), and you gain basically nothing since exception handling is generally implemented to not cause performance penalties if nothing is thrown...

This function cannot throw: as discussed in the comments, initializing the parameter is not part of the function’s execution, and the return is implicitly a move (although it cannot be elided since it is from a function parameter).

NB1 a move could throw though it is considered as bad design. In the case of std::string it is mark as noexcept so remove_suffix can be noexcept also.
NB2 a snippet to illustrate what has been said in comments, see lines 9 and 24
